# Google chrome's caching behaviours for css sub-resources fetched with `url()` is unexpectedly aggressive

Tags: css, google-chrome, http, http-headers

CSS looks ordinarily:

```
background-image: url(/path/to.png);
```

Caching on the server side is set to be `cache-control: no-cache`.

All resources are cached as expected (in cache, must revalidate), but sub-resources referred by `url(...)` in css stylesheets google chrome caches extremely agressively: the browser doesn't revalidate them.

That's how the dev tools look like for what I'm talking about:

[image]

Firefox works as expected: every resource is revalidated (and http 304 is returned).